# How can a Background image to fit into a cell table ( allow distorted )

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to fit a Background a cross image into a cell table. 
The image allow distorted but not repeat.
When the browser expand, the image must expand too and otherwise.

I tried a lot combination.
Set background-size to cover or contain but still not works.

```css
.selected {
  background-image: url("http://www.pd4pic.com/images/red-box-cross-square-wrong.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<div class="w3-container w3-row">
  <table class="w3-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: Image not 100percent width]

Hope you guys can help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `background-size:100% 100%;` this will help you

```css
.selected {
  background-image: url("http://www.pd4pic.com/images/red-box-cross-square-wrong.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<div class="w3-container w3-row">
  <table class="w3-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you but image is stretch because the size of div is not according to image.

```css
.selected {
  background-image: url("http://www.pd4pic.com/images/red-box-cross-square-wrong.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<div class="w3-container w3-row">
  <table class="w3-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
      <td class="selected"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```